# What is the difference between I love flowers vs I love the flowers

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english

I want to know what is the difference between these two examples:

> 1. I love flowers so much!
> 2. I love the flowers in my garden so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I love flowers

This is a generic statement, and it says that you feel attraction towards flowers in general.

> I love the flowers

Here, you are talking about some specific flowers. Eg. Flowers someone has given to you, shown you e.t.c